# Magento - Product Order

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.7

I want to list all the items ordered in alphabetical order on the email confirmation and also in invoice (email version). In addition, I would love to list the products in this list by category, if that's possible. Any ideas how to do this? I would of thought it would be fairly easy, but I'm struggling to work it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try ? show codes

Comment: Yes. This can be done. First you need to sort the products which are in cart. So automatically the same structure will be followed by the invoice....

Comment: Thank you for your response. Pavan Kumar - how do I sort the products in the cart?